# Не анимируется setBounds

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В некоторых случаях setBounds при выставленном duration не анимируется, а переносится мгновенно.

```
 var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    bounds: [[55.927508859617696, 37.8442784658615],
            [55.929851911467324, 37.84709478532714]]
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    myMap.setBounds([[55.72450466, 37.64446792], 
                     [55.99352968, 37.97332318]], 
                    {duration: 5000})
    .then(function(val) {
      console.log('fine ', val);            
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('err ', err);            
    });
  }, 2000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/038jobLr/

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Загрузка карты может запаздывает? Что если Вам создание карты тоже возвращать промисом, а потом уже все остальные действия инициализировать?

Comment: @AlexeyZolotov Если разница между зумами не такая большая то аналогичный код проходит нормально. Если timeout поставить в 20000 - всё аналогично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увеличьте значение опции [`maxAnimationZoomDifference`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#param-options.maxAnimationZoomDifference) у карты. Например, до `Infinity`, если вы хотите, чтобы плавный зум происходил **всегда**.

```js
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
  bounds: [/* ... */]
}, {
  maxAnimationZoomDifference: Infinity
});
```